# Retrieve Lync contact from a phone number in an UCMA application

Tags: c#, sip, lync, ucma

I have a C# managed Application that runs on a Lync 2013 Server and uses MSPL. I route every call from MSPL to the application and handle it there. Lync to Lync calls work fine and their `to` Header is in the form `sip:user@domain.com`. But when a call from outside the network (non-lync like mobile phone etc.) to the workphone of a Lyncuser is started, the Uri is like `sip:+12341234@domain.com;user=phone` (sip:[workphone]@domain). Passing this string to the Presence Retrieval function does not work.

```
var sips = new string[] { phone }; // The "To" number
presenceService.BeginPresenceQuery(sips, categories, null, null, null);
```

This always returns an empty result. How can I first retrieve the user associated with the phone number to get its presence?

Comment: When you say a 'call from an external source', is this external source a federated network? If the external source is just a phone rather than a lync/skype/etc client, it does not have any presence whatever you do.

Comment: I meant calls from a phone or mobile phone that are outside the network. I already found a "solution" myself but I was hoping that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
public static UserObject FindContactBySip(string sip)
{
    return UserList.FirstOrDefault(u => u.HasSip(sip));
}

private static void InitFindUsersInAD()
{
    PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    user.Name = "*";
    var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
    var result = searcher.FindAll();

    var sipList = new List<string>();
    UserList = new List<UserObject>();

    foreach (var res in result)
    {
        var underlying = (DirectoryEntry)res.GetUnderlyingObject();
        string email = string.Empty, phone = string.Empty, policies = string.Empty;

        foreach (var keyval in underlying.Properties.Values)
        {
            var kv = keyval as System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection;
            if (kv != null && kv.Value is string)
            {
                if (kv.PropertyName.Equals("msRTCSIP-PrimaryUserAddress"))
                {
                    email = (kv.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                }
                else if (kv.PropertyName.Equals("msRTCSIP-Line"))
                {
                    phone = (kv.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                }
                else if (kv.PropertyName.Equals("msRTCSIP-UserPolicies"))
                {
                    policies = (kv.Value ?? string.Empty).ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phone) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            var userobj = new UserObject(email, phone, policies);
            UserList.Add(userobj);
        }
    }
}
```

First I initialize the `UserList` (List // Custom class) from the AD. Then I call `FindContactBySip` and check if the provided SIP equals the Email or Phone of the User.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two other ways to solve your problem.

In MSPL you can:

```
  toContactCardInfo = QueryCategory(toUserUri, 0, "contactCard", 0);
```

Which gives you:

```
  <contactCard xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/09/sip/contactcard"" >
  <identity >
  <name >
  <displayName >
  Lync User</displayName>
  </name>
  <email >
  lync.user@xxx.com</email>
  </identity>
  </contactCard>
```

You can turn the email address into a sip address.  This only works if your lync setup uses email address for sip addresses.

The other method is to use '[P-Asserted-Identity](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3325.txt)' sip header to determine who the phone call is being routed to/from.  The only problem is that it doesn't show up in the inital invites (as that would be for the From side anyway), but in the 180 ringing response from the Lync Client.

```
  P-Asserted-Identity: <sip:lync.user@xxx.com>, <tel:+123456789;ext=12345>
```

So if you wait for the 180 ringing response then I would recommand that you use P-Asserted-Identity method and you don't even need to escape out of MSPL for it!